# Cannot understand why I can't read java cookies by name

Tags: javascript, cookies

okay, I have been pulling my hair out for hours with this one and now that I'm completely bald I'm throwing in the towel and seeing if anyone can point to the (I'm sure very simple) mistake that is turning my code into useless junk.

I have two pages, the first one the user enters 3 inputs and they are saved as cookies:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function CC()
      {
        var V1Box = document.getElementById("V1");
        var V2Box = document.getElementById("V2");
        var V3Box = document.getElementById("V3");
        var V1 = V1Box.value;
        var V2 = V2Box.value;
        var V3 = V3Box.value;

           document.cookie = "V1 = " + V1 + "; path=/";
           document.cookie = "V2 = " + V2 + "; path=/";
           document.cookie = "V3 = " + V3 + "; path=/";

        window.location = "pg2.html";
      }

</script>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="Generator" content="Serif WebPlus X5">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">
<title>db2</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
.Artistic-Body-C
{
    font-family:"Verdana", sans-serif; font-size:27.0px; line-height:1.19em;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="wpscripts/wpstyles.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body text="#000000" style="background-color:#ffffff; text-align:center; height:900px;">
<div style="background-color:transparent;text-align:left;margin-left:auto;margin
right:auto;position:relative;width:375px;height:900px;">
<form id="form_1" action="" method="post" target="_self" style="margin:0px;">
<input type="button" style="position:absolute; left:271px; top:12px; width:81px;
height:22px;" value="Submit" onClick="CC()">
<input type="text" id="V1" name="V1" value="" style="position:absolute; left:23px;
top:12px; width:227px;">
<input type="text" id="V2" name="V2" value="" style="position:absolute; left:23px;
top:46px; width:227px;">
<input type="text" id="V3" name="V3" value="" style="position:absolute; left:23px;
top:80px; width:227px;">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The second page is supposed to get the cookies previously set and isolate there values:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function getCookie(){

var allcookies = document.cookie;
   cookiearray  = allcookies.split(';');

   for(var i=0; i < cookiearray.length; i++){
      var name = cookiearray[i].split('=')[0];
      var value = cookiearray[i].split('=')[1];
        if(name == 'V1'){var V1 = value;}
        if(name == 'V2'){var V2 = value;}
        if(name == 'V3'){var V3 = value;}
   }

document.getElementById("V1").innerHTML += V2;
document.getElementById("V2").innerHTML += V1;
document.getElementById("V3").innerHTML += V3;
}

</script>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="Generator" content="Serif WebPlus X5">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">
<title>db2</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
.Artistic-Body-C
{
    font-family:"Verdana", sans-serif; font-size:27.0px; line-height:1.19em;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="wpscripts/wpstyles.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body text="#000000" style="background-color:#ffffff; text-align:center; height:900px;">
<div style="background-color:transparent;text-align:left;margin-left:auto;margin
right:auto;position:relative;width:375px;height:900px;">
<div style="position:absolute;left:23px;top:12px;">
    <div class="Wp-Artistic-Body-P">
        <span class="Artistic-Body-C" id="V1">V1: </span></br>
        <span class="Artistic-Body-C" id="V2">V2: </span></br>
        <span class="Artistic-Body-C" id="V3">V3: </span></br></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue I have is that the code does not recognize any of the names in these if statements -- even if I echo the name and value; it will echo "V3" and the corresponding value, but the V3 variable is never set and will echo as "undefined". I am losing my mind trying to figure out how it can have the name set as "V3" but then not recognize "if(name == 'V3'){var V3 = value)" and keep var V3 undefined. I have even tested "if(name != 'V3'){var V3 = value)" and, even when echoing the name and getting "V3" it will interpret name not equaling V3 in the if statement and actually set the appropriate V3 variable value. I don't understand how it can name everything properly, retrieve everything properly, and then not recognize the name in an if statement to set the variable properly -- doesn't matter if I'm calling V1 or V2 or V3; it just doesn't see those names inside of the if statements.

I'm sure this is something stupid in my syntax or there's a typo or something, but after three hours of trying to fix it myself I'm clearly blind to it. I recognize that there are other, simpler ways to manipulate user inputs, but my project as a whole requires that I use cookies and that I am able to retrieve them by name on different pages; if you have any suggestions for how I can accomplish this criteria in a better way I would be very much appreciative, however just getting my current code to work properly would be a big help and my scalp (which as I continue to claw for any remaining strands of hair has begun bleeding profusely) will very much thank you for it.

Comment: java or javascript? Last time I checked they were 2 different things :)

Comment: JSLInt your JavaScript code and see the errors.

Comment: Thanks, I got turned on to JSLInt from all this so at the very least that's something that will help me in the future. Unfortunately in this case it gives me a bunch of minor issues that don't affect application and then cuts out before addressing my issue (at 47%) so even with that tool I'm lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at where V1, V2, V3 are declared!

```
    if(name == 'V1'){var V1 = value;}   <-- what happens if not true
    if(name == 'V2'){var V2 = value;}   <-- what happens if not true
    if(name == 'V3'){var V3 = value;}   <-- what happens if not true
```

They will not be defined.

You need to have

```
var v1 = "";
var v2 = "";
var v3 = "";
```

declared and drop the var inside the ifs.

JSLint/JSHint would have pointed out this error.

---

Third issue is innerHTML can not have +=

```
document.getElementById("V1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("V1").innerHTML + V1;
```

---

Other issue is whitespace in the names. Cookies have a space after the ; which you do not account for in the name.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Unfortunately this still doesn't seem to be fixing my issue -- now var V3 comes back empty instead of undefined. It would appear that is still doesn't recognize name as being V3 (even though it tells me so if I echo "name"). I am wondering if you wouldn't mind showing me what your solution looks like "all together" as I simply may be defining the empty values out of proper sequence (currently have it just before I start my "for" loop)

Comment: Thanks again, unfortunately I still am not getting the cookie data. I have taken this code apart and re-assembled it a thousand different ways and I am confident at this point that the issue lies directly with it not interpreting the name correctly in the if statement. It's really perplexing and frustrating; if I call the name it gives me the last in the loop -- "V3", however it won't recognize "if(name == 'V3')" as ever occurring. Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated; don't know if I can handle another day of getting nowhere.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Eg33F/1/ simple debugging shows the error. Watch the alerts, what do you see?

Comment: Thank you SO much for your help -- seriously, I was starting to get buggy! I am curious, if you can tell me and don't mind doing so, I can see how the spaces got there (duh -- can't believe I didn't think of that possibility, I danced around it so many times!) but am curious if there is a way to prevent this from occurring? Sorry if it is a silly question, just can't help myself to ask; javascript, clearly, is not all that well known to me yet. Either way thanks again!

Comment: `cookiearray  = allcookies.split(/;\s?/);`

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function getCookie(){

var allcookies = document.cookie;
   cookiearray  = allcookies.split(';');

   for(var i=0; i < cookiearray.length; i++){
      var name = cookiearray[i].split('=')[0];
      var value = cookiearray[i].split('=')[1];
        if(name == 'V1'){var V1 = value;}
        if(name == 'V2'){var V2 = value;}
        if(name == 'V3'){var V3 = value;}
   }

document.getElementById("V1").innerHTML += V2;
document.getElementById("V2").innerHTML += V1;
document.getElementById("V3").innerHTML += V3;
}

window.onload = getCookie; 
</script>
```

I don't believe the getCookie function was ever run.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately this still doesn't seem to give me what I'm looking for -- V3 returns "[object HTMLSpanElement]"